# Dynamic Data Lists in Liferay

Tags: validation, liferay, liferay-6, dynamic-data-list

I have text field in my **dynamic data list** but there should be only email id's. 
How to write **validation** for the text field??? There is only one required field in dynamic data lists

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use javascript validation